# evince frames.pdf, but "no protocol specified"

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the introduction to tf tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

when prompting "evince frames.pdf", it should be frames tree.

But instead, it turns out to be problem:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247118/evince-frames.pdf,-but-%22no-protocol-specified%22/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem, using a workaround. The problem is caused by the fact that I am running the terminal as a root.
In ubuntu, it is no good to run GUI application as a root, sudo. Reference to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299586
Thus, the solution is quite simple, just change to the common user, and it works!

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0